# how to hide OpenGLRenderer in debug (android studio)

Tags: android, debugging

I got this in debug every seconds, how to hide these messages and stay my debug logs ?

```
11-17 13:20:01.885 18135-18135/ru.elron.app D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x607c1008>
11-17 13:20:01.886 18135-18135/ru.elron.app D/OpenGLRenderer: drawRect multiDraw RelativeLayout @41d8ab88 paint 0x5efe8830 id 5 style 0 AA 0 color 0xff168ce3
11-17 13:20:01.887 18135-18135/ru.elron.app D/OpenGLRenderer: drawRect multiDraw View @41d8d720 paint 0x60efcce0 id 5 style 0 AA 0 color 0x10ffffff
11-17 13:20:01.889 18135-18135/ru.elron.app D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x607c1008>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem. It seems to be some bug in the phone (if you can't switch it off in developer options). The way to (temporarilly) solve it:

add in AndroidManifest.xml to the `<application>` the tag `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`

You can then remove them by release

Comment: Hi Alexander,  I got the same issue with Samsung Galaxy S5(Native Android App),the above solution did not work for me.Please Help me ASAP. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you can create a logcat filter in Android Studio. Put there in "Log Tag" only needed tags divided by "|"(like AndroidRuntime|System.err|<tag_of_your_package>), set "Package Name" and check "Regex".